# Is there a way to convert an cbz / epub / pdf comic to support Amazon's "panel reading"?

Tags: epub, kindle-paperwhite, conversion, mobi, cbz

I got some CBZ/Epub comics from Humble Bundle, and I'm trying to replicate the functionality of comics bought directly from Amazon, where I can double tap a panel to display it full screen, and as I "turn the page," I navigate through the remaining panels in the right order.

I tried using Kindle Comic Converter and Calibre, but neither seemed to work, not sure if I'm doing something wrong. Has anyone replicated that functionality successfully?